# updating an object's field using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

My problem is that I have to update a field of an object based on ID field.
There are some eager loaded collections/objects in that object.So, If i load that object either using get/load or using Criteria then it will load all the child objects also.

If I use Projections to have only the column I want, it returns me String but I want the object to be returned somehow so that I can just set its field to updated value and use hibernate's automatic dirty checking feature.

So, could anybody please let me know how can I achieve that without writing SQL query?

Comment: write an HQL query http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

Comment: If loading the associations cause a performance problem, and you don't always want these associations to be loaded, why are they eagerly loaded in the first place? Fix the problem, rather than working around it.

Comment: actually in my project this is how it has been assigned..so can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using jpql to update the field?

e.g.

like it is done in this example:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_bulk_ops

```
    UPDATE Publisher pub SET pub.status = 'outstanding'
    WHERE pub.revenue < 1000000 AND 20 > (SELECT COUNT(mag) FROM pub.magazines mag)
```